# When exactly is the MouseLeave event triggered?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

According to this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.uielement.mouseleave(v=vs.105).aspx) Article : "The MouseLeave event is raised in response to a touch event occurring outside the object's bounding area.". But in implementation am finding it being triggered while releasing a tap on the object's bounding area (precisely like OnMouseLeave).

So how do I get it to fire while tapping outside the UI Object's boundary?

Answer (score 0):

I am new to C# and StackOverflow, but I thought I might contribute what I found. I did a quick Google search of "" and found [this article](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/304641/detect-a-click-outside-a-guiobject.html) about detecting clicks outside of a GUI.

Here is a quick method/description (found in link) which detects the clicks outside of a rectangle drawn over the GUI. "When you use a GUI window or group / area, you can use its Rect to check if the mouse is inside."

```
Rect windowPos = new Rect(10,10,200,150);

    void OnGUI()
    {
        Event e = Event.current;
        windowPos = GUI.Window(0, windowPos, drawWindow, "MyWindow");

    if (e.type == EventType.MouseDown && !windowPos.Contains(e.mousePosition))
        {
             // Click was outside of the GUI window
        }
    }

    void drawWindow(int aID)
    {
        // draw the window content
    }
```

Just go read on that page. It seemed to answer their question before.

Good luck!

Comment: This wont work for what am doing since I've many nested UI elements (dynamically created) and I need out of boundary tap detection for each. I was wondering if I could make the MouseLeave event work like its supposed to.